# android and ssl

Tags: android, ssl

r will exchange XML files. For now I use normal sockets to deliver files from app to app but I need to use SSL connetion so I want use java SSLSockets. My problem is that I really dont know how to do that. I searched information on the internet a lot but I do not find nothing usefull. Can anyone give me some example of Android-Server SSL connections? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't search enough: [JSSE Reference Guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html). Running sockets in Android is not particularly special, try it out. One thing to note is that you cannot use the system properties mentioned in the guide (`javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, etc.), you have to setup your trust/key stores from code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty.

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;

public class EasyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

  /**
   * Connection manager that uses our SSL certificate.
   */
  @Override
  protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();

    // Register for HTTP.
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

    // SSL Socket.
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    // Register for HTTPS.
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));

    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }
}
```